# Taking LSD while having sex and dying

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Decades ago I read a story about a pilot who had a one-night stand with a stewardess native to Papua who had blue eyes due to some genetic changes in the future. They took LSD together and he realized he was dying during sex. What's the name of the story and/or author?

Comment: "Decades ago" could be two decades ago or seven decades ago. Please try to narrow it down a little more. Was there anything science-fictional or fantastic about the story?

Comment: It sounds the sort of thing that might have been in one of the *New Writings in SF* collections, or in one of Moorcock's *New Worlds* collections. Do either of those ring a bell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Schwartz Between the Galaxies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40965) by Robert Silverberg might be a possibility. It can be read on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Science_Fiction_Monthly_v03n03_1976-03) or [lightspeedmagazine.com](http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/schwartz-between-the-galaxies/).

Excerpt:

> Then a smiling JAL stewardess parts the curtain of his cubicle and
> peers in at him, jolting him from one reality to another. She is
> blue-eyed, frizzy-haired, straight-nosed, thin-lipped, bronze-skinned,
> a genetic mishmash, your standard twenty-first-century-model mongrel
> human, perhaps Melanesian-Swedish-Turkish-Bolivian, perhaps
> Polish-Berber-Tatar-Welsh. Cheap intercontinental transit has done its
> deadly work: All Earth is a crucible, all the gene pools have melted
> into one indistinguishable fluid. Schwartz wonders about the
> recessivity of those blue eyes and arrives at no satisfactory
> solution. She is beautiful, at any rate. Her name is Dawn—O sweet
> neutral nonculture-bound cognomen!—and they have played at a
> flirtation, he and she, Dawn and Schwartz, at occasional moments of
> this short flight. Twinkling, she says softly, “We’re getting ready
> for our landing, Dr. Schwartz. Are your restrictors in polarity?”
>
> “I never unfastened them.”
>
> “Good.” The blue eyes, warm, interested, meet his. “I have a layover
> in Papua tonight,” she says.
>
> “That’s nice.”
>
> “Let’s have a drink while we’re waiting for them to unload the
> baggage,” she suggests with cheerful bluntness. “All right?”
>
> “I suppose,” he says casually. “Why not?”

Comment: Yes, that's it, Ayshe. Thanks much. Unfortunately, I forgot my password to the account I used to post this question, so I'm answering via another account. (Forgot Password restoration didn't work because the software is intolerant of a delay in clicking the link, and my email was horribly slow the past few days.) I hope you read this note of gratitude before some CoC cop deletes this answer as "not being a real answer".

Comment: Interesting story, btw. I just went and read it.

Comment: So, it turns out not to be clear at the end that Schwartz took the "siddhartin" psychedelic, or even that he was dying (rather than going crazy and drifting off into his fantasy world). Still, a good story with more relevance today than many others of the 1970s.